# How to get "primary" user of a remote computer

Tags: c#, wmi

I need to know how to get the name and domain of the primary user of a computer, remotely. I define the primary user preferably as the user logged on most times, or longest time over a period. Alternatively, if this is impossible, as the user currently/last logged on.

Currently, i scan an Active Directoy for all computer objects in an OU. I then loop though them, and try to get the name of the user using WMI.
I look in `Win32_ComputerSystem` to see if UserName returns a value. If this is not the case, i look in `Win32_LogonSession` and get the username for all LogonTypes that equal 2 or 10. If this returns none, or multiple values, i discard the result and look in `Win32_Process` for all non-system processes and define the primary user as the user with most processes running.

There are several problems with my approach:

1. `Win32_ComputerSystem` - UserName is often null.
2. `Win32_LogonSession` often return multiple or no values. There can be only 1 primary user.
3. Looking in `Win32_Process` is kinda ridiculous, since this will only return me the user with most processes, most likely not the primary user.
4. If no user is currently logged on, looking in `Win32_Process` returns no value and none of the 3 steps might return a value.

My 3 approaches might get me the current user. Does anyone know of a way to get the primary user? Or at least a better way to get the current. Not necessarily using WMI.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have administrator privileges on the remote computer and sharing access 
you can use Computer Management and select to 
connect to other computer and see what users and groups are on that computer. 
Or you can  use TS Remote Administration or Remote Desktop if the remote computer has that capability.

Use `psexec.exe` (www.sysinternals.com) to run commands on a remote pc:

```
psexec \\pc1 net user | find /i "Steve" 
psexec \\pc1 c:\tool\psloggedon | find /i "Steve"
```

1) Find if John Black has an account on PC1.

2) Find if he is currently logged on. 
Use `psloggedon.exe` that uis is another SysInternals tool.

Check this also: http://www.wisesoft.co.uk/scripts/vbscript_display_username_of_user_on_a_remote_computer.aspx

Also if you want to find the User Name of the currently logged user on a remote computer using the remote computer IP then Go to the command line an type `nbtstat -A <IP of remote computer>` This will return all of the NetBIOS names registered on the computer, one of which is the username.